# Navigate to a specific View Controller inside a TabBarController from AppDelegate, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a TabBarController with two tabs Cases & Settings

I would like to take the user to CaseSummaryTVC which is nested like this 
TabBarController > Cases (NavigationController, Storyboard Id = 'tvcNav' ) > CasesTVC (TableViewController) > CaseSummaryTVC (TableViewController, Storyboard Id = 'CaseSummaryTVC').

I am using the below code in AppDelegate, which takes me to the 'CaseSummaryTVC' but **doesn't show the TabBar on the bottom**.

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let navController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tvcNav") as! UINavigationController

        let caseSummaryTVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CaseSummaryTVC") as! CaseSummaryTVC

navController.pushViewController(caseSummaryTVC, animated: true)


self.window?.rootViewController = navController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting your window's rootViewController to be 'navController', which doesn't seem to be wrapped in a UITabBarController.

I'm not sure what your storyboard looks like, but it sounds like you have the view hierarchy setup correctly there.

You could do one of the following:

1) Remove the programmatic view controller instantiation and have the storyboard take care of setting the rootViewController to the UITabBarController.

2) Instantiate the UITabBarController programmatically like you have done here with the other view controllers, and make sure it's set up to have the navController as one of it's tabs.

Comment: I agree with the first suggestion, OP needs to pick between interface builder or the programmatic route to handle the root view controller because the problem is that OP is pushing to the wrong instance of the navigation controller, which explains why the tab bar is omitted.